# Beautifulsoup Cannot FindAll

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape nature.com to perform some analysis on journal articles. When I execute the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

query = "http://www.nature.com/search?journal=nature&order=date_desc"

for page in range (1, 10):
    req = requests.get(query + "&page=" + str(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text)
    cards = soup.findAll("li", "mb20 card cleared")
    matches = re.findall('mb20 card cleared', req.text)
    print(len(cards), len(matches))
```

I expect Beautifulsoup to print "25" (the number of search results) 10 times (one for every page) but it doesn't. Instead, it prints:

```
14, 25
12, 25
25, 25
15, 25 
15, 25
17, 25
17, 25
15, 25
14, 25
```

Looking at the html source shows that there should be 25 results returned per page but Beautifulsoup seems to be confused here and I can't figure out why.

**Update 1** In case it matters, I'm running on Mac OSX Mavericks using Anaconda Python 2.7.10 and bs4 version 4.3.1

**Update 2** I added a regex to show that req.text does indeed contain what I'm looking for but beautifulsoup is not finding it

**Update 3** When I run this simple script multiple times, I sometimes get a "Segmentation fault: 11". Not sure why

Comment: It works for me you are missing `()` for  `print` if your python is 3.x

Comment: @Michael: When you run this code, it prints "25" 10 times in a row?? I get 14,12,25,15,15,17,17,15,14.

Comment: yes `25` 10 times. start new python interpreter and run again your code to see

Comment: I tried throwing this code into a python script and executing from the command line ("./test.py") and still not seeing "25" 10 times. In fact, I am getting different results each time I run it. This is really perplexing me!

Comment: _Looking at the html source shows that there should be 25 results returned per page_ - are you looking at the page source for each loop iteration?

Comment: @soon: Yes, I'm looking at the page source for the first five pages. Why do you ask? What are you suggesting?

Comment: Are you looking at them in browser, or using python?

Comment: @soon: Both in the browser and printing req.text for each page. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: Please, save output of `req.text` somewhere and then try to paste it directly to `soup = BeautifulSoup(**here**)`. Will `soup` find 25 blocks? If no, please, paste the output to, for example, [pastebin](http://pastebin.com).

Comment: @soon: I could do that but I simply added a regex findall to show that what I'm searching for is contained. See updated/edited. If tha doesn't convince you then I can pastebin it.

Comment: Strange. Your code works fine for me (Python 2.7.9 and Python 3.4.3). Could you, please, update your post with Python and `bs4` exact versions (`bs4.__version__`)?

Comment: I simply copied your code and ran it, I've got 25's all over the place! No 14's and so.. (Py3.4.0) Try updating bs4 in case you have an older version.

Comment: @soon: I added exact versions to post (see update 1)

Comment: I've just downgraded my `bs4` version to `4.3.1` and the code still produces 25. Could you reinstall all your tools and run the script again?

Comment: Still the same thing (using Anaconda on a Mac) after reinstalling bs4 and requests. I tested on two separate Mac OSX machines and found the same results.

Comment: On a third Mac, I am able to get "25" 10 times. However, Anaconda was not installed or used on this machine. Not sure what the difference is and how to go about resolving this.

Comment: @slaw well, it looks like it should be related to the way `BeautifulSoup` parses the HTML and the underlying parser it uses under-the-hood (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers). But I was unable to reproduce what you've got. There is smth else involved I suspect, but try to specify the parser explicitly, e.g. `soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')`, or `soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')`.

Comment: @alecxe: That did the trick! I had to specify 'html.parser' and it corrected the problem. However, it didn't recognize 'html5lib' for some reason and asking me if I need to install a parser library. If you post an answer then I will accept it! Thanks for your help and reference to the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [differences](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers) between the [parsers used by `BeautifulSoup` under-the-hood](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).

If you don't specify a parser explicitly, `BeautifulSoup` would [choose the one based on rank](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use):

> If you don’t specify anything, you’ll get the best HTML parser that’s
>   installed. Beautiful Soup ranks lxml’s parser as being the best, then
>   html5lib’s, then Python’s built-in parser.

Specify the parser explicitly:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
```